# CakePHP: Doesn't find child tables

Tags: cakephp, model, find, model-associations

I have three models: Project, Student, and Vote.
The following code is the relationship between them. In the Project model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Student' => array(
    'className' =>'Student',
    'foreignKey'=>'project_id',
    'order' => 'Student.studentName DESC',
),
'Vote' => array(
    'className' =>'Vote',
    'foreignKey'=>'project_id',
));
```

In the Student model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project'=>array(
        'className'=>'Project',
        'foreignKey'=>'project_id'
));
```

And in the Vote model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project'=>array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
));
```

However, when I call this function (in the Project model):

```
public function getApprovedProjects(){
    $approvedProjects = $this->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(
    'Project.approved' => 1)));
    return $approvedProjects;
}
```

This is the data that I get:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Project] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0
                [projectName] => MyProject
                [semester] => GAME
                [description] => Test project
                [imageLink] => 
                [approved] => 1
            )

        [Student] => Array
            (
            )

        [Vote] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Project] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [projectName] => CRIA STUFF
                [semester] => CRIA
                [description] => Cria project
                [imageLink] => 
                [approved] => 1
            )

        [Student] => Array
            (
            )

        [Vote] => Array
            (
            )

    )
)
```

It doesn't find any of the students or votes associated with this Project, even though they exist and I think it should. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions to help me out? I have a deadline coming up for work, and I want to avoid having to wait until I can meet with other programmers.

Comment: Your results look correctly formatted for projects that _don't_ have any students or votes. Check your query log and most likely you'll find that the result is accurate for the data you have.

Comment: I don't know why there's no Student data, but Vote model has specified foreign key as:  `'foreignKey' => 'id'` instead of `'foreignKey' => 'project_id'`. Also note that in your models you should use foreign key table names like: `project_id` instead of camelCase

Comment: please show some data of these tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I fixed the problem.

It turns out, Cake doesn't like doing associations with data that has an id of 0. All of my other fetches worked, and as soon as I changed all of the data in the table to have an id that wasn't 0, my find worked.

So, in the future, don't add entries to your table with an id of 0. Start at 1.